# double floating number to binary conversion

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement a 25 taps FIR filter in matlab. Some of the filter weights are negative and some are positive, generated by `rcosdesign` command.

I have to use these filter weights and inputs for another design that requires binary conversion of these two. My weight vector is

```
[ 0.0030,   0.0327,    0.0471, 0.0265, -0.0275, -0.0852,  -0.0994, -0.0321, 0.1190, 0.3112, 0.4720,   0.5346, 0.4720, 0.3112, 0.1190 , -0.0321, -0.0994,   -0.0852, -0.0275,  0.0265,    0.0471,  0.0327, 0.0030,  -0.0188]
```

How can I convert these values into binary numbers with word length 16? I have read many other answers that suggest typecast and some user defined functions, but these didn't work for me. Especially typecast, it makes my weight vector values zeros.

Comment: What is your expected output? How do you want to represent these values in binary? IEEE754? Integer values multiplied by some scaling factor?

Comment: @beaker Thanks for your reply. I am sending inputs to a multiplier which takes binary inputs and produces a result into decimal. e.g: if input is weight entry -0.0852 and second input is 2, it should be converted into binary first and then multiplier multiplies these two binaries. my result should be -0.1704 in decimal at the end.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to go about this, depending on the range of values you expect to be working with. Unless we know what binary value you expect to see for a given decimal value, we'd just be throwing out options blindly. If you have MATLAB 2018b or later (which I don't have access to), you *might* be able to use the new half-precision floating-point type. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/half.html) and [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2017/05/08/half-precision-16-bit-floating-point-arithmetic/).

Comment: I think you're a little confused about what "binary" means here. Those original numbers _are_ binary numbers; they're just binary floating-point numbers instead of binary integers. They're only being converted to decimal numbers for display purposes. What the other commenters say is right: we need to know specifically what kind of binary number you're trying to map these values to.